# How can I play an animation from a non-Scene class using manim?

Tags: python, manim

I was trying to do a Neural Network animation, and I found a class online, which I modified to suit my needs. Basically, the class looks like:

```
class NeuralNetworkMobject(VGroup):
    ...
    ...
    def change_edge_color(...):
        edge = random.choice(n1.edges_out) # n1.edges_out is a VGroup, and edge is Line 
        # I want to play the edge fade in animation from this method.
        # I've tried to do:
        NeuralNetworkScene.play(FadeIn(edge)) # NeuralNetworkScene is the actual scene
```

But, the program gives an error, saying that:

```
  File "neural.py", line 171, in set_neuron_edge_color
    NeuralScene.play(FadeIn(n_edge))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/manimlib/scene/scene.py", line 845, in wrapper
    self.update_skipping_status()
  AttributeError: 'FadeIn' object has no attribute 'update_skipping_status'
```

How can I play an animation form a non-Scene class?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I tried everything I can, including instantiating the main scene and then trying to play the animation (which you obviously shouldn't) to directly accessing the Scene.play() method (which didn't work either). So, as a solution I came up with:

```
class MainScene(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        ...
        neurons = NeuralNetworkMobject()
        your_animation_function(neurons)

    def your_animation_function(self, neurons):
        self.play(FadeIn(neurons))
        ...
```

While this approach does solve the problem, just for curiosity I am asking that is it possible to play an animation from a non-Scene class?

Thanks,